# angular2 material grid tile in component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<md-grid-list cols="3">
    <product *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product"></product>
</md-grid-list>
```

The **product** component contains a **md-grid-tile**.

The problem:
The tiles are not visible (but they are rendered in the DOM). It works well if I put the **md-grid-tile** directly under the list but I'd like to keep my code clean and to use my own component...

Is there something I'm missing? Maybe I can add some CSS hack to show the tiles?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can't you just put the `product tag` inside the `md-grid-tile tag` instead? And do the looping on the tiles, but keep passing the "product"  into your product component.

Comment: That's what I did first and it works, but I want to handle the click event on the whole tile in the ProductComponent

Comment: I see your point. But isn't it enough to put a div around the rest of the html in your product template and have the click event set on it? And set `height: 100%; width: 100%;` on the product component (could be that you want to use the :host selector in your component css for that)

Comment: Yes it is... haha it was pretty simple actually, thanks! I added the width/height to the product tag with the :host selector

Answer (score 2):

From a comment on the question:

> But isn't it enough to put a div around the rest of the html in your product template and have the click event set on it? And set height: 100%; width: 100%; on the product component (could be that you want to use the :host selector in your component css for that)

This is how I solved it:

```
<md-grid-list cols="3">
    <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let product of products">
        <catalog-product [product]="product"></catalog-product>
    </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

and in the product component's scss:

```
:host{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```